# How to make jquery validation engine work at bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validation-engine

I'm trying to use [this plugin](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) at my bootstrap page. It'll be very simple. Just show a message if the field is `empty`. But, I can't make it work! I don't understand why, it's not working. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/9kwr5jdw/).

Comment: This does't seems to be problem with bootstrap, i tried to change your code removing all bootstrap related stuff, but it is not working either. So something else is wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to load the correct locale, then you have to include a way to validate the form on the submit button.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v5v2x7u7/

```
<form role="form" id="formID">
    <div class="form-group validation-content">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input value="" class="form-control validate[required]" type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group validation-content">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input value="" class="form-control validate[required,custom[email]]" type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group validation-content">
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea value="" class="form-control validate[required]" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="validate();">Submit</button>
</form>

validate = function(){
    $("#formID").validationEngine('validate');
}
```